# Espressione "mi fa una pippa"

Tags: idioms, meaning, vocabulary

Ciao,

Ho sentito l'espressione *mi fa una pippa* diverse volte. 
Però non ho mai capito cosa significhi.

Grazie

Comment: L'espressione _mi fa una [pippa](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pippa2_(Sinonimi-e-Contrari)/)_ ha lo stesso significato che in _mi fa un baffo_, ma in modo più scurrile (così come _mi fa una [sega](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sega/)_). Esistono varianti ancor più turpi (che ometto).

Comment: ...cioè, oltre a eventuali interpretazioni letterali della frase, ha il senso di “mi è del tutto indifferente”, “non mi muove affatto”.

Comment: Bruno, se l'hai sentita diverse volte a proposito di cose dette da te, quale che sia il significato, dovresti iniziare a preoccuparti.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Il significato letterale è a sfondo sessuale.
2. Un significato acquisito è 'mi fa un baffo', 'non mi interessa'.
3. Un'altra interpretazione è 'non è alla mia altezza', 'non mi intimorisce'.

Comment: Be', non autocensuriamoci: il significato letterale è *Mi fa una sega*, che, come altre espressioni sessuali dove il piacere si presume sia provato solo da una delle due parti (il celebre *Me lo puppa* dei toscani), allude a un rapporto di dominio e quindi di superiorità da parte di chi subisce l'atto nei confronti di chi lo esegue. Da ciò si capisce bene il perché e il carattere dei significati metaforici.
Comunque è un'espressione decisamente volgare sebbene dal tono scherzoso.

Comment: Grazie Mille! Ho capito adesso cos'è :)